# How to simulate random observations from a specific distribution?

Tags: simulation, computational-statistics, random-generation

I am asking for a general approach about how to construct algorithms akin to, for example, the `rnorm` function in R given that one has, say, a closed-form probability distribution function and corresponding cumulative distribution function (and quantile function, too, if needed).

How to go about it?

I am not interested in the normal distribution *per se*, nor interested in a specific language, but the approach.

Comment: ecdf meets uniform distribution?

Comment: @EngrStudent Don't answer in the comments. Also spell it out. :)

Comment: [The Wikipedia page on pseudo-random number sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-random_number_sampling) has some more approaches, depending on the situation.

Comment: If you have the quantile function $Q=F^{-1}$ (if numerically stable and  not too slow), the [inverse probability integral transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling#Definition) is sufficient (though not necessarily very fast by comparison with other techniques). It's worth learning about the main methods of [rejection sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling), for example; there are a variety of nifty methods that use it in one way or another, the polar method is one; another example is [the ziggurat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziggurat_algorithm)

Comment: (My comment, being links-only, is not really suitable as an answer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The Art Of Computer Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming) Vol.2 Chapter 3 has all the different methods used. I highly recommend reading the entire chapter.

The simplest and most obvious method is by using the inverse cumulative distribution function (CDF): $F^{-1}(p)$, which is also the *quantile* function. Generate uniform random numbers and plug them into the inverse CDF, you'll get what you're looking for. This is what I usually do in [Excel](http://exceluser.com/formulas/statsnormal.htm#random%20number) `NORMS.INV(RAND())`, because I'm too lazy to code [Box-Mueller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform) myself.

This is not the method used for Normal distribution. For "named" distributions, such as gaussian, there are often more efficient methods e.g. Box-Mueller.

Inverse CDF computation can be expensive, because rarely you have the closed form expressions. There are, of course, approximations, such as [this](http://home.online.no/~pjacklam/notes/invnorm/) for Gaussian inverse CDF. In contrast, Box Muller approach uses certain properties of Gaussian distribution to reduce the algorithm to calculation of closed form expressions using square root, log and sine functions, all of which are implemented in the transcendental function modules of CPUs these days. The specialized random number generators will exploit special features of the distributions to get performance or precision edge over the generic method described above.

A very different approach is used in Markov Chain Monte Carlo methods. I'm not getting into this unless it's what you're looking for.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. Could you amplify what "more efficient methods" gains *are* from, e.g. Box-Mueller in your third paragraph (just a sentence or two more clarifying the why an alternative to the CDF$^{-1}(\text{uniform 0/1 data})$ might be desirable? If you have a *short* answer as to why one might prefer MCMC for the final paragraph, that'd be swell too. Not looking for more than a motivation here. :)

Comment: @Alexis added a blurb on Box Muller.

Comment: Knuth has many methods - perhaps all the important ones - and is definitely worth spending the time to read and understand, but -- as fond as I am of the book -- I'm pretty sure it doesn't have *all* methods. Since 1998  (the latest edition of that volume to my knowledge) some new methods have come out, for example.

Comment: The ultimate reference on methods for generating from probability distributions is Devroye's [Non-uniform random variate generation](http://luc.devroye.org/rnbookindex.html), which is available for free on Luc's webpage.

Comment: +1 Good heavens that is a beast! I am grateful both for your reference to it, and for Devroye's making it freely available for any purpose.

Answer (score -3):

So here is an ECDF plot:

[image]

Here is the code used to make it:

```
library(latticeExtra)

y<- rnorm(n=1000,mean=0, sd=1)

ecdfplot(y)
```

Lets look at it.  It is comprised from 1000 samples of a standard normal distribution.  The x-axis is the magnitude of the sample, and the y-axis ranges from 0 to 1.

The idea then is that you can make something that looks like this, but map from y to x.  Imagine that you drew 1000 samples from the uniform distribution, and then mapped them from y to x.  Your output would be a decent approximation of the standard normal distribution.

As long as you can make a continuous eCDF then you can use this method to approximately sample from the distribution.

So interpolation is a fair way to engage this.

```
p <- ecdf(y) #create function using data
fy <- p(sy)   #find values on sorted data (needed for interp)

yi <- sort(runif(n=1000)) #sample from uniform, sort

#use interpolation to map to distro of interest
x2 <- interp1(x=fy,y=sy,xi=yi,method="pchip")

#randomize if you need it
x2 <- sample(x2,length(x2),replace=FALSE)

#plot updated cdf and then compare
ecdfplot(x2)
```

So why **E**cdf?

- It is data driven.  If you have an analytic function for the
  distribution then you can evaluate it at the points and make the
  ecdf.  If you have only previous data and no analytic function then
  you can make the ecdf.  If you want to hand-make your own
  distribution using any valid mathematic method - as long as you end
  up with numbers at the end, you can use this method to approximate
  it.
- It is fast to code, and computers run very fast.
- It works on data - and sometimes you can have cdfs for which analytic inverse does not exist.

References:

- http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2013/07/22/the-inverse-cdf-method.html
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling (aka Smirnov transform)
- http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/examples/nonparametric-estimates-of-cumulative-distribution-functions-and-their-inverses.html

Comment: Pardon me if I am being obtuse. My original question specified a CDF, **CDF$^{-1}$** and pdf, so I don't see how the *empirical distribution function* is of interest.

Comment: Empirical CDF is a kind of CDF. You can get an inverse CDF from it very easily. If you already know CDF, then going through ECDF route is a long detour

Comment: For an engineer - good enough is good enough.  If it works, then it works.  Sometimes that isn't good for a math or stats person making a proof.

Comment: @EngrStudent, how would you use this approach to generate exponential distribution? You'll have to generate the exponential r.v. first to plug into eCDF, but you don't yet have the exponential r.v.! I mean this line in your code `y<- rnorm(n=1000,mean=0, sd=1)`. You assume that you already have `rnorm`, if that was the case there wouldn't be a question. eCDF is an approach when you get the sample from unknown distribution, it's like bootstrapping in this regard

Comment: Ziggurat sounds like a variation on shooting method - so it depends on fast closed form of CDF.  Box-Muller is about the basis - if their analytic basis isn't compatible with your distribution then it loses its advantage.  I would think that inverse CDF method with some sample filtering and polynomial interpolation could be quite fast.  You could stick a b-tree between the random uniform and the interpolant.  If you used the right quadrature to pick your sample-points then you could have a small "n" for the O(n*log(n)) operations.

Comment: To second Aksakal's point, this does not answer the question: when given a density function $f$ or a cumulative distribution function $F$, to produce an ecdf requires a sample from $f$ or $F$, which defeats the purpose of using it to simulate from $f$ or $F$.